# calling a Java method by AJAX

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

Actually I've been reading about this for a while but I couldn't understand it very well.
Here is a snippet of the Servlet  "ProcessNurseApp" :

```
if (dbm.CheckExRegNumber(Candidate.getRegNumber()) == true) {

            // Show him an alert and stop him from applying.    
            out.println("<script>\n"
                    + "     alert('You already Applied');\n"
                    + "</script>");
            out.println("<script>\n"
                    + "     window.history.go(-1);\n"
                    + "</script>");
        }
```

So when the form named "ApplicationForm" in the "Nurses.jsp" get submitted it goes to that method in servlet after some Javascript validation.

My issue is that I want to call that method 
`if (dbm.CheckExRegNumber(Candidate.getRegNumber()) == true)`
in the JSP page without getting to servlet so I can update values without refreshing the page. I've been reading that using ajax with jQuery would be the best way to do that, so can anyone help me of calling the above if statement from jQuery by AJAX.

Comment: Did you try writing at least some code in javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Try an ajax call to  the servlet(not possible without calling servlet) to check whether the function returns true or false then return a flag according to the value(true or false). On that basis you can show an alert or anything else.

For ajax call, you can use:

```
$.post( "ajax/Servlet_Url", function( data ) {  if(data==true)  alert("You already Applied"); else  window.history.go(-1);});
```

Refer to following Link for more details about jQuery post request.

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Answer (score -1):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
$("#searchUserId").attr("placeholder", "Max 15 Chars");
$("#searchUserName").attr("placeholder", "Max 100 Chars");
$.ajax({
    url:"../../jsp/user/userMaster.do",
    data: { drpType : 'userType',lookType : "1" },
    success: function (responseJson) {
            var myvalue = document.getElementById("userTypeKey");
            for(var val in responseJson) 
              {     
                  valueType = val;   
                  textOptions =  responseJson[val];
                  var option = document.createElement("option");
                  option.setAttribute("value",valueType);
                  option.text = textOptions;
                    myvalue.add(option);
                    if(valueType == myvalue.value)
                    {
                        option.selected = "selected";
                    }
               }
        }
    });
```

});

Comment: JQuery ajax call via struts action to go to java Action class(execute) and execute/return Java Object as needed.